# terminology: XML schema versus XML application

Tags: xml, xsd, docbook, dita

From what I read, DocBook and DITA are applications of XML, and HTML is an application of SGML:

- http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31286&seqNum=17
- http://xml.silmaril.ie/differences.html
- http://cs.au.dk/~amoeller/XML/xml/applications.html
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Generalized_Markup_Language#Applications

However, I cannot understand whether there is any difference between "applications" and "schemas"?   Are these the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ***application*** of a technology or standard (e.g. XML) to a given area such as publishing (e.g. DocBook or DITA), lending (e.g. MISMO), business documents (e.g. UBL, XBRL), and so on, merely means that the tech/standard has been *applied* to that area.  It is in this sense that some refer to DocBook and DITA etc as ***XML applications***.

A ***schema*** is a particular design artifact that constrains the vocabulary and grammar of a data format.  An ***XML Schema*** (XSD) is a W3C Recommendation for schemas for XML documents.  Each of the above mentioned *XML applications* has developed XML schemas for the particular sets of XML document in their respective sectors.

There is another use of *application* that refers specifically to an executable program.  In this sense, an *XML application* is simply a specific program that processes (often an sector-restricted set of) XML documents.

Comment: Thanks! **"XML-application = XML-based markup language applied to some specific domain, for example publishing or lending"** - is it correct? If the answer is "yes", then second question: **"Is it possible/common for some application, for example DocBook, to have multiple schemas?"**

Comment: Yes, and, yes, there can be multiple XSDs within a domain: There's typically an evolution of versions of each XSD, and there're often separate XSDs for subareas within a domain.

Comment: Thanks again! But not sure I completely understand. For example, the domain is publishing. Within this domain we have 2 applications: DocBook and DITA. You said: "**there can be multiple XSDs within a domain**". So, it could be understanded in that sence that you mean DocBook's XSD and DITA'a XSD. In total, it gives us 2 XSDs and for that reason it could be sayed that there are "**multiple XSDs within publishing domain**". But I asked about multiple XSDs within each XML-application, i.e multiple XSDs within DocBook or within DITA. :-)

Comment: Yes, my comment applies within DocBook or within DITA as well.